# Why is the exponential distribution chosen to model service time in Queuing theory?

Tags: exponential-distribution, queueing

Why is the exponential distribution chosen to model service time in Queuing theory  ?

Answer (score 1):

The exponential distribution incorporates the assumption that the *hazard rate* is not dependent on the time spent in the queue.

The hazard rate is the instantaneous rate of an event (via Wikipedia page on Survival analysis):

\begin{equation}
\lambda(t) = \lim_{dt\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\Pr(t\le T < t+dt)}{dt \cdot (1-F(t))}} = \frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}
\end{equation}

For an exponential distribution $f(t) = b \exp(-b t)$ and $1-F(t)=\exp(-b t)$, therefore $\lambda(t)=b$, i.e., constant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So (as far as I understood )the exponential distribution is chosen to model service time just because the event rate is constant ?

Comment: @user3914897 That's probably the reason, but I suspect it's not so realistic. The time between arrival of customers might be realistically modeled as exponentially distributed, but service times are quite a different matter.

Comment: It's all to do with the Markov property isn't it? Non exponential queues are modelled as M/G/n queues (much more complicated)